# SCP protocol error : unexpected <newline>

Tags: windows, scp

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

SCP выдает такую ошибку win 11. Как побороть? Нагугленный вариант с if не работает.

Comment: Пароль через copy-paste вводите?

Comment: Пробовал и так и вручную. Результат один и тот же.

Comment: 1. Выложите вашу проблему текстом, а не обрезанной картинкой. 2. Попробуйте scp -o LogLevel=DEBUG